# Do I need an SSL certificate for www and non www?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

If my server is set up to redirect users who type the non www URL, e.g.

```
example.com -> www.example.com.
```

Do I need to get a certificate for both domains:

```
example.com, www.example.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If a user types in https://example.com, the TLS handshake between their browser and your server happens before the redirect. Users will see an error message in their browser indicating the site's certificate is invalid.

If you're using Let's Encrypt you can include both www and non-www domains in the same certificate. Most other certificate vendors also do this on request.

Comment: DigiCert does it automatically.